# Unable to connect from ec2 server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to login on ec2 instance server, but I am getting me errors like

> Too many authentication failures for ubuntu,

or

> Permission Denied (Public key).

when I connect  to the server with `ssh -i "pem_file" ec2_name@public_ip`

When yesterday, I was login in server, it's worked but after exit from server and again trying to login it's giving me errors which is mentions above.

Comment: I also try to changes in etc/ssh/ssh_config file.

Comment: Make sure you have `ssh-add <private_key>` first.

Answer (score 51):

So if you get this message

> Too many authentication failures for ubuntu,

It's usually because you have tried too many private_keys to authenticate against the user `ubuntu` in your server.

You can get more info here:

https://superuser.com/questions/187779/too-many-authentication-failures-for-username

Try running this:

```
ssh-add -l
ssh-add -D
```

You may have too many keys stored in your local ssh-agent.

If you get this:

> Permission Denied (Public key).

it generally means that your public key is not in the ~ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys file on the server.  You can actually debug by creating a snapshot of your EBS volume (if you are using EBS). Then create a new volume from the snapshot and then attach the volume to another running EC2 instance.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-attaching-volume.html

That way you can see what's in your /home/ubuntu/.ssh/ directory

Comment: in my case i used : ssh -i /path_to_local_rsa/id_rsa -o 'IdentitiesOnly yes' -i "ec2.pem" username@ip

Answer (score 34):

What eventually worked for me:

```
chmod 400 priv_key.pem               #or what you named it
ssh -o 'IdentitiesOnly yes' -i priv_key.pem ec2-user@ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: with the  -o 'IdentitiesOnly yes' option in place, it works. Never seen this problem before.

Answer (score 6):

In my case restarting my MacBook helped.

Comment: Worked for me as well.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, running

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
```

fixed the issues.

You can get a better explanation here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/351725/why-eval-the-output-of-ssh-agent

Answer (score 1):

its ubuntu@publicip not ec2-user@publicip

Comment: Thank you Pearly, however I understood the question to be that they were getting permission denied responses. I am not critiquing the question or asking for clarification. I believe this does answer the question, as this is a very common problem with logging into ec2s. Most people presume it is always going to be`ec2-user@publicip`, or in his case he used `ec2_name@publicip` whereas specifically for ubuntu machines you have to use this `ubuntu@publicip`. Not doing that he will get the `Permission Denied (Public key)` error and then eventually `Too many authentication failures for ubuntu`.